# How to create a selection list in KivyMD

Tags: ios, list, menu, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create a menu/selection to choose certain values from a list using KivyMD. I want it to look similar to how these lists look on IOS apps. I've included an image from the 'Fitbit' app for reference of what I'm trying to replicate.

[the type of menu/selection I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNTCU.jpg)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, there is no such implementation of time picker in KivyMD. There is a Picker class - https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/pickers/

[image]

[image]